# How to stage only single line of changes in Git CLI?

Tags: git

I added three lines of code in a row:

```lua
local function delete()
    return nil -- TODO: Stub
end
```

And I want to stage and commit only the first and the last ones. Adding it with `-p` or `-i` option does not help - the whole hunk will be added. I know that I can do this with GUIs like Git Extensions. But is it possible to stage single lines instead of hunks using command line?

Comment: (Hitting `?` at the interactive add (`git add -p`) prompt would have given you good hints about using `e` like @shadowfax1497 rightfully suggested.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While interactively staging using the `git add -p` command, you have the option `s` to split a hunk further into smaller hunks. But, in this case, this hunk cannot be split further. So, you can use the manual edit option `e`

1. Select the `e` option during the interactive staging

```
+local function delete()
+   return nil -- TODO: Stub
+end
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]? e
```

2. You will now be in the "manual hunk edit mode", which shows the hunk being staged.

```
+local function delete()
+   return nil -- TODO: Stub
+end
```

3. To not stage the second line, remove the second line and exit the "manual hunk edit mode"

```
+local function delete()
+end
```

4. You have now staged only the first and the third line